# "non grid based", "non-grid based", "non grid-based" or "non-grid-based"

Tags: adjectives

I would like to express "an interpolation scheme which is *not* based on grids". But among the following options:

"non grid based", "non-grid based", "non grid-based" or "non-grid-based"

I am not sure which one I should use. I have tried google and [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) and found no answer. I neither found any straightforward guide or rule from some related posts (eg. [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300315/nonstop-non-stop-or-non-stop),[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272998/non-optional-or-non-optional),[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/is-the-use-of-a-hyphen-between-non-and-an-adjective-strictly-necessary)) on this site. Which one is better for a native speaker?

---

Edits:

1. I am not sure about the rule when there are multiple adjectives with some hierarchy among them.
2. I guess it should be "a non grid-based interpolation".(?)

Comment: And could you say why those questions you linked don't help? That would assist answerers to know exactly what the difficulty is which those questions don't explicitly address.

Comment: @choster, thanks! but it seems that the link points to some other post.

Comment: @gamebm Sorry, I made a copy/paste error. The correct link is *[Non in front of hyphenated adjective](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227267)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a hyphen between "non" and "grid" because "non" is not a word on its own, just a prefix. You should also have a hyphen between "grid" and "based" to indicate that they are not to be interpreted as separate adjectives. Therefore "non-grid-based" is the correct choice.

[Non in front of hyphenated adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227267/non-in-front-of-hyphenated-adjective) addresses this well.